# Javascript - efficiently insert multiple HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, appendchild

I'd like to create a `select` element with a list of a user's Facebook friends (obtained as a JSON object).  I hardcode `<select id="friends"></select>` into my HTML, then use the following Javascript code to parse the JSON and insert each friend as an `option` of the `select` element:

```
var msgContainer = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
    msgContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode('<option value="'+response.data[i].id+'">'+response.data[i].name+'</option>'));    
}
document.getElementById("friends").appendChild(msgContainer);
```

This almost works, except that it inserts `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`.  How can I fix it, and is there a more efficient way to insert multiple HTML elements using pure Javascript (not JQuery)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not sure why you're creating a text node, but it would seem that you want to create `option` elements, so you could use the `Option` constructor instead.

```
var msgContainer = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
    msgContainer.appendChild(new Option(response.data[i].name, response.data[i].id));
}
document.getElementById("friends").appendChild(msgContainer);
```

---

Or you can use the generic `document.createElement()`.

```
var msgContainer = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    var option = msgContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("option"));
    option.text = response.data[i].name;
    option.value = response.data[i].id;
}
document.getElementById("friends").appendChild(msgContainer);
```

---

It's nice to have a helper function for creating elements and setting properties at the same time.

Here's a simple example of one:

```
function create(name, props) {
    var el = document.createElement(name);
    for (var p in props)
        el[p] = props[p];
    return el;
}
```

It can be expanded to cover some specific needs, but this will work for most cases.

You'd use it like this:

```
var msgContainer = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    msgContainer.appendChild(create("option", {
        text: response.data[i].name,
        value: response.data[i].id
    }));
}
document.getElementById("friends").appendChild(msgContainer);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is one way more efficient?

Comment: @1'': I wouldn't give performance a second thought here. Personally, I'd make an element creator helper function that lets you create any element and set a bunch of properties at the same time.

Comment: The second variant is inefficient and pretty bad practice (appending elements in a loop), so the first one is preferred.

Comment: @dfsq: That's not true. They're both appending elements in a loop.

Comment: Yes, bro, it's true. There is a difference between appending elements to document fragment and appending them to DOM. Significant difference.

Comment: @dfsq: They're both appending to the document fragment.

Comment: Damn, my bad! You are right, this is my day. Anyway, I upvoted your answer, so no offence :)

Comment: @dfsq: None was taken. Just making sure everything is clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your for loop instead:

```
var o = document.createElement('option');
o.setAttribute('value', response.data[i].id);
o.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response.data[i].name));
msgContainer.appendChild(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need similar functionality, you can generate an html snippet using template literals and insert it using `innerHTML` property. Plus you can set attributes and selected while iterating over the items:

```js
const el = document.createElement('select');
el.innerHTML = ['John', 'Sally', 'Betty'].reduce((acc, prev, i) => {
  if (i === 1) {
    return acc + `<option selected>${prev}</option>`;
  }
  return acc + `<option>${prev}</option>`;
}, '');

const root = document.querySelector('#app');
root.appendChild(el);
```

In modern browsers this is faster than creating elements one by one imperatively.